# How to navigate to another screen on back key press in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigation, screen, event-listener, react-native-navigation

I am trying to make an alert when the user clicks back button where he will be offered with two options, Yes or No. If the user clicks "No" the user will stay on that screen and if the user presses "Yes" then, I want some different screen to be shown.

Basically I want to prevent user from going back to the previous screen and instead redirect the user to some another screen.
Here is the example useEffect code that I am trying to make this work:

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      Alert.alert(
        'Registration Process',
        'Are you sure you want to cancel the registration process?',
        [
          {
            text: 'Yes',
            style: 'destructive',
            // If the user confirmed, then we dispatch the action we blocked earlier
            // This will continue the action that had triggered the removal of the screen
            onPress: () => {
              // navigation.dispatch(e.data.action);
              navigation.navigate('SignUp');  // On pressing Yes, user should be shown this screen.
            },
          },
          {text: 'No', style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {}},
        ],
      );
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```

After running the app, when I press "Yes" I get treated with the alert box again and again.

Comment: This method will go on to run infinitely..Check my answer for a better implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `hook` and call it on `backpress` on when user tries to leave the page

Create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located.

Inside that create a file called `useBackHandler.ts`

Inside `useBackHandler.ts` paste this

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

export function useBackHandler(handler: () => boolean) {
  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handler);

    return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handler);
  }, [handler]);
}
```

Then in your `RegisterScreen` create a function to execute on `backpress` or when user wants to goBack like this

```
const AlertConfirmation = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Registration Process',
      'Are you sure you want to cancel the registration process?',
      [
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          style: 'destructive',
          onPress: () => {
            navigation.navigate('ScreenOne');
          },
        },
        { text: 'No', style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
      ]
    );
  };
```

I've created a Snack for you to see working example..

Check [this](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/backpress-handler) out.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Can you explain the working behind this? . I have never created a custom hook.

Comment: Yeah Sure!...What Happens here is whenever we press `Back` button the BackHandler event listener gets triggered and stops the `default action` of going back...and it then Performs `AlertConfirmation` function which shows the Alert box.

Comment: Why won't my method worked though? Why does it run infinitely? I think it probably runs infinitely as the screen keeps on getting removed on Clicking "Yes" I suppose?

Comment: Because as you know in `useEffect`'s dependencies you included `navigation` prop...this means that the code block you write inside `useEffect` will run whenever there is a change in `navigation` prop...So now...Whenever you pressed on 'YES` option in alert it again goes to execute the `useEffect` part and thus it goes on to run infinitely.